# Add raw data points to jp.int (sjPlot)

Tags: r, visualization, interaction, nlme, sjplot

For my manuscript, I plotted a lme with an interaction of two continuous variables:

Create data

```
mydata <- data.frame( SID=sample(1:150,400,replace=TRUE),age=sample(50:70,400,replace=TRUE), sex=sample(c("Male","Female"),200, replace=TRUE),time= seq(0.7, 6.2, length.out=400), Vol =rnorm(400),HCD =rnorm(400))  
mydata$time <- as.numeric(mydata$time)
```

Run the model:

```
model <- lme(HCD ~ age*time+sex*time+Vol*time, random=~time|SID, data=mydata)
```

Make plot:

```
sjp.int(model, swap.pred=T, show.ci=T, mdrt.values="meansd")
```

The reviewer now wants me to add the raw data points to this plot. How can I do this? I tried adding geom_point() referring to mydata, but that is not possible.
Any ideas?

Update:
I thought that maybe I could extract the random slope of HCD and then residuals HCD for the covariates and also residuals Vol for the covariates and plot those two to make things easier (then I could plot the points in a 2D plot).
So, I tried to extract the slopes and use these to fit a linear regression, but the results are different (in the reproducible example less significant, but in my data: the interaction became non-significant (and was significant in the lme)). Not sure what that means or whether this just shows that I should not try to plot it this way.

get the slopes:

```
  model <- lme(HCD ~ time, random=~time|SID, data=mydata)
  slopes <- rbind(row.names(model$coefficients$random$SID),  model$coef$random$SID[,2])
  slopes2 <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(slopes), nrow=144, byrow=T))
  names(slopes2)[1] <- "SID"
  names(slopes2)[2] <- "slopes"
```

(save the slopes2 and reopen, because somehow R sees it as a factor)

Then create a cross-sectional dataframe and merge the slopes:

```
  mydata$time2 <- round(mydata$time)
  new <- reshape(mydata,idvar = "SID", timevar="time2", direction="wide")
  newdata <- dplyr::left_join(new, slop, by="SID")
```

The lm:

```
modelw <- lm(slop$slopes ~ age.1+sex.1+Vol.1, data=newdata)
```

Vol now has a p-value of 0.8 (previously this was 0.14)

Comment: sjPlot will use the [ggeffects-package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggeffects) from one of the next updates on. You could try the `ggpredict()` function to compute marginal effects for the interaction (see also package vignette) and use the `plot ()` method, with the argument `rawdata = TRUE`.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for helping! I tried it out, but when taking the mean +/-sd for the predictor, it seems to be impossible to add the raw data (not same length) and when not selecting values for ggpredict, the plot function tries to plot lines for every subject (with running out of color options error). Ideally I would like to plot mean+/-sd (like sjp.int) and then add the raw data points. Is there a way to do this? maybe somehow I can combine sjp.int with ggpredict/plot?

Comment: You can select specific values inside brackets: `ggpredict(model, terms = c("age [30,50]", "time [1,3,5]"))`. You could also write me an email, if it's more convenient than responding here.

Comment: Thanks! I have just sent you an email